# Firebase deploy returns error at tsc command

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've setup a Firebase project to create some basic Firebase Functions.
In the project I'm using TypeScript

Following the [Firebase official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#initialize_a_firebase_project) I created my project.

The last step, `firebase deploy --only functions`, gave an error with the `tsc` command.

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to ‘my-project’…

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /path/to/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /path/to/functions
> tsc

node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,95): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,96): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts(60,116): error TS1005: ';' expected.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /some/path/.npm/_logs/2019-02-03T00_10_30_573Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

It seems that some of the Firebase library code does not pass the `tsc` compile/transpile step.
I'm looking for a way to make this deploy step pass.

I've followed the suggestion given at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/749), which included:

- Adding `--skipLibCheck` to the `tsc` command
- Adding `skipLibCheck` to the project's generated `functions/tsconfig.json`
- Adding `isolateModules` to `functions/tsconfig.json`
- Adding `./functions/node_modules/@types` to the `typeRoots` array in the `functions/tsconfig.json` file.
- Adding `dom` to `compilerOptions.lib` in `functions/tsconfig.json`

None of the above steps have worked for me.

How can I make my deployment to Firebase succeed?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941420/4378475

Comment: Hey Rick, what did you do to solve this issue? Changing the versions as below didn't work well. Did you manage to solve this ?  

THANKS!!

Comment: A year and a half ago, that did the trick. See the accepted answer, upgrade to the latest typescript version, clear cache and retry, these are the things I would do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ran into same issue, was able to deploy after upgrading typescript library to 3.3.1 version and do npm install.

In package.json file set 
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    **"typescript": "~3.3.1"**
  },

Note: you can remove all changes described in your post.

Comment: Thank you, I was using `typescript: 2.8.4` and updating to `~3.1.1` did the job.

Comment: This answer didn't fix the problem for me. But there were several successful solutions in the GitHub issue the OP mentions. I found the one about adding type roots to the tsconfig.json to be the best: https://git.io/JeZrh

Comment: In my experience TS, FB, Angular, Ionic move so quickly that 7month old issue and answer is very outdated.

Answer (score 7):

this works for me :
add this line to tsconfig within the functions folder:

"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],

This is part of "compilerOptions" block worked for me