# How can I write a Scheduled Function in TypeScript to reset userHighScore for all users in my Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an iOS/swift game with a leaderboard, and I'd like the scores to all reset to 0 every Monday at 12:00am.

I'm all set up with Cloud Functions and have code in my index.ts that will run every Monday at 12:00am, but I'm not sure how to write code in TypeScript to update all userHighScores to 0.

Here's what I have so far in index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

functions.pubsub.schedule(‘0 0 * * 1’).onRun((context) => {


    // This code should set userHighScore to 0 for all users, but isn't working 

    .ref('/users/{user.user.uid}/').set({userHighScore: 0});


console.log(‘This code will run every Monday at 12:00 AM UTC’); 
});
```

After saving the above code and running "firebase deploy" in Terminal, this is the error I see:

```
Found 23 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/derencewalk/.npm/_logs/2019-05-19T00_39_38_037Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

There aren't any errors when I firebase deploy just the console.log code, so I'm pretty sure it's just that the .ref line of code is malformed. What would be the proper syntax?

Thanks in advance for any help.

***Update***

Here is the working code that updates all userHighScores for all users in the database once a week on Monday at 12:00am:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

export const updateHighScores = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * 1').onRun((context) => {

//console.log(‘This code will run every Monday at 12:00 AM UTC’);
const db = admin.database();
return db
  .ref('users')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    const updates:any = {};
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot:any) => {
      const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      updates['users/' + childKey + '/userHighScore'] = 0;
      updates['users/' + childKey + '/earnedExtraTime'] = 0;
    });
    return db.ref().update(updates);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

Firstly, `ref()` is a method of a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Database), in the Admin SDK for Node.js (which is the SDK to be used in a Cloud Function if you want to interact with the Realtime Database). Therefore you would need to do something like `admin.database().ref(...).set({userHighScore: 0});`

Secondly, declaring a `Reference` with `'/users/{user.user.uid}/'` will not work, as you need to pass a string or a an existing Reference to the `ref()` method (or nothing at all, in which case it will point to the root of the Database). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Database#ref.

Thirdly, if you want to modify all the children nodes under the `users` node, you first need to query for them with the `once()` method, and then write the new value for each of them, with the `set()` or `update()` methods.

I make the assumption that your database structure is as follows:

```
databaseRoot
    - users
        - user1_uid
            - userName: "xyz"
            - userHighScore: 66
            - otherDataElement: ....
        - user2_uid
            - userName: "abcd"
            - userHighScore: 32
            - otherDataElement: ....
```

Therefore I propose to modify your code as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();


export const updateHighScores = functions.pubsub.schedule(‘0 0 * * 1’).onRun((context) => {

    // This code should set userHighScore to 0 for all users, but isn't working
    //console.log(‘This code will run every Monday at 12:00 AM UTC’);
    const db = admin.database();
    return db
      .ref('users')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
          updates['users/' + childKey + '/userHighScore'] = 0;
        });
        return db.ref().update(updates);
      });
});
```

Note that we add the Admin SDK (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk) and we initialize it (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_without_parameters)

Comment: Thanks so much! I am getting errors, but have resolved some of them. 

"error TS1002: Unterminated string literal" was fixed by re-typing the apostrophes in ".schedule('0 0 * * 1')" so that they are straight. 

The next said "error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature." Seems to have been resolved by adding this code above the function: "interface updates {[key:string]: any;}" (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193262/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-window-has-no-index-signatur/42193905)

Comment: But I am still getting all the same "nmp ERR!"s from the original post. I tried updating to TypeScript 3.3.1 (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498868/firebase-deploy-returns-error-at-tsc-command), but still all the errors. Do you know what these errors are occurring? Thanks again!

Comment: All errors have been resolved and the code deploys and works perfectly! :) I'll update the post now to show the working code. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It just needed ":any" added in two places: after "const updates" and ".forEach(childSnapshot"

Comment: Glad that I could help. Do not hesitate to update the code accordingly, as I was not able to test it!