# Firebase deploy errors in function-builder and handle-builder using typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm

I am getting 4 errors when running `firebase deploy` using firebase cloud functions.

The errors are coming from files that I have not touched.

```
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts:64:136 - error TS2707: Generic type 'Request<P>' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.

64         onCall: (handler: (data: any, context: https.CallableContext) => any) => import("./cloud-functions").TriggerAnnotated & ((req: express.Request<import("express-serve-static-core").ParamsDictionary, any, any, import("express-serve-static-core").Query>, resp: express.Response<any>) => void) & import("./cloud-functions").Runnable<any>;
                                                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.d.ts:64:252 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/harrisa/dev/apps/exerciser/functions/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Query'.

64         onCall: (handler: (data: any, context: https.CallableContext) => any) => import("./cloud-functions").TriggerAnnotated & ((req: express.Request<import("express-serve-static-core").ParamsDictionary, any, any, import("express-serve-static-core").Query>, resp: express.Response<any>) => void) & import("./cloud-functions").Runnable<any>;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ~~~~~

node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/handler-builder.d.ts:21:36 - error TS2707: Generic type 'Request<P>' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.

21         onRequest: (handler: (req: express.Request<import("express-serve-static-core").ParamsDictionary, any, any, import("express-serve-static-core").Query>, resp: express.Response<any>) => void) => HttpsFunction;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/handler-builder.d.ts:21:152 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/harrisa/dev/apps/exerciser/functions/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Query'.

21         onRequest: (handler: (req: express.Request<import("express-serve-static-core").ParamsDictionary, any, any, import("express-serve-static-core").Query>, resp: express.Response<any>) => void) => HttpsFunction;
```

I have tried updating firebase functions and firebase admin npm packages but the errors still persist.

The errors came about after removing a few packages from npm. However, I reverted my changes in git back to a point where it was working, but the errors are still there.
Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

I managed to fix the issue following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498868/firebase-deploy-returns-error-at-tsc-command) and in-particular `Adding skipLibCheck to the project's generated functions/tsconfig.json`

I still think this is just ignoring the problem, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

go back to stable versions.
I made this decision to solve it.

```
"firebase-admin": "8.9.2",
"firebase-functions": "3.3.0",
```